# How dangerous is it to leave a base unattended?

Tags: no-mans-sky

If I let my tools unattended** (like [Refiner](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Refiner), [Storage Container](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Storage_Container), Rover etc.), how easy is it that I get robbed?

** filled with resources

What exactly can an "enemy" steal from my base?
Can everyone steal the content of all my tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable network play in the options. Press <kbd>P</kbd> (on PC) and set network play to "Off". If you do that, you are perfectly safe.

If you have network play enabled, then players can join your session via "Join random game". If a players joins your session, he is placed in a planetary system near you (or even in the same system). In the ingame chat, you will se the notification "[Player x] has joined your game", and if the player enters the same system as you, "[Player x] has entered the system".

The first 3 players to join are automatically placed in your "group". The next twelve players to join will also be in your session, but not in your group, for a total of 16 players per session.

Players **in your group** can:

- Take items out of refiners
- Pick up any portable equipment
- **Delete** everything in your base
- Manipulate the terrain around your base
  -- including burying it or removing terrain around it

As far as I know, they can not steal from storage containers and your star ship (and neither your freighter inventory or exocraft inventories, for what its worth). But everything else is up for grabs.

They are also able to destroy the cargo pods of your freighter, and loot the freighter contents that way - if they survive the ensuing space battle.

Comment: I am assuming that you need to be online for them to be able to join your session, and that you'll get notified of a player joining your session?

Comment: Yes, obviously you need to be online for others to join your game session. And yes, you get notified.

Comment: Man they really need to not let random players into your group. Group should be by permission only.

Comment: @Jason_c_o I wholeheartedly agree.