# Is there a way to prevent players from joining my game?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I play in creative and build bases but I’ve had times where random people join and delete parts of my bases. How to I make it so people can’t join?

Comment: See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/337172/how-dangerous-is-it-to-leave-a-base-unattended

Answer (score 4):

[Cross posting from this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/337172/how-dangerous-is-it-to-leave-a-base-unattended)

> You can disable network play in the options. Press P (on PC) and set
>   network play to "Off". If you do that, you are perfectly safe.
>
> If you have network play enabled, then players can join your session
>   via "Join random game". If a players joins your session, he is placed
>   in a planetary system near you (or even in the same system). In the
>   ingame chat, you will se the notification "[Player x] has joined your
>   game", and if the player enters the same system as you, "[Player x]
>   has entered the system".

via [@Polygnome](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/26862/polygnome)